# Reading in a file Android

Tags: java, android, file, csv

I made this method which reads in a csv file and stores the data into an arraylist contained in a map Map..This method worked fine in java alone..But when I implemented it in android it didn't work and the app crashes..I've been trying all day to fix it so any help is very much appreciated thanks..below is my attempt at using this method in android by reading in the csv file from the sd card. It seems to crash when I use the get method. Below you can see logcat.

```
public class New extends Activity  {
private static Map<String, List<String>> values;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "Android/data/"
                    + getPackageName().toString()+ "/" + "SOPARC.csv");
        values = parseCsv(fr, ",", true);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      values.get("Date").get(2);
    }


    public static Map<String, List<String>> parseCsv(Reader reader, String separator, boolean hasHeader) throws IOException {
        Map<String, List<String>> values = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
        List<String> columnNames = new LinkedList<String>();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String line;
        int numLines = 0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(line)) {
                if (!line.startsWith("#")) {
                    String[] tokens = line.split(separator);
                    if (tokens != null) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; ++i) {
                            if (numLines == 0) {
                                columnNames.add(hasHeader ? tokens[i] : ("row_"+i));
                            } else {
                                List<String> column = values.get(columnNames.get(i));
                                if (column == null) {
                                    column = new LinkedList<String>();
                                }
                                column.add(tokens[i]);
                                values.put(columnNames.get(i), column);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ++numLines;
                }
            }
        }
        return values;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: post stack trace error.. or Try this:

http://code.google.com/p/secrets-for-android/source/browse/trunk/src/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVReader.java

Comment: Does this make any help?

Comment: that doesn't look relevant.

Comment: my apologies..wrong part..I think this should b the problem illustrated now

Comment: you still didn't say which line it is but guessing from the NullPointer, it is probably CSV parsing fails and then `values` is null and then you call get on it.

Comment: Yeah this is the problem...any idea why  the parsing fails? :/

Answer (score 0):

You must also have added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file if you access files at `getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

If that wasn't the case, may be [StrictMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html)?

You can test by `StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(StrictMode.allowThreadDiskWrites())` adding to `onCreate()`.

However it is bad practice to do file access on main thread since they can take arbitrarily long times.

Comment: Like I say the code works prefectly in when I debug it in java (reading a file from my computer)..just when I implement it in android the problem arises. Must be a problem reading in the file from my sd (android) card but i'm not sure

Comment: @user3156801 Did you added permission to access SD card?

Comment: yeah put <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> into the manifest. I tried also FileInputStream istead of FileReader but made no difference

Comment: @user3156801 this would have been much easier if you have added the error message :)

Comment: As you can see i've added an logcat..hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If this worked in Java (I can't test) and doesn't work in Android, there might be some issues, such as:

- try to remove your code from the Activity's `onCreate()` method - it's generlly bad practice to overload `onCreate()`, move to `onResume()` or add a button for it.
- second - use an `AsyncTask` to read the file on a separate thread, not on main (UI) thread, as it might cause crashes / ANRs.